# How to send html file to client and embed data from server inside it?

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to send The following html page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello World</h1>
    <h1> $$MY_DATA </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want $$MY_DATA to be a data injected to the html file from the server. Do you know how to do it without the need for Ajax calls?

Comment: Please share code how you  are sharing now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a HTTPServlet. Please read the documentation here [Servlet Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

The doGet method can send this to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a templating engine. Vert.x-web supports a number of them, such as Thymeleaf, Handlebars, etc.

See here: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_templates